Issue with Mamba Transformer Implementation for Medical Image Detection
I am currently working on a medical image detection problem on the Kaggle platform and attempting to use the Mamba transformer for this task. However, when I ran the code below, I encountered an issue (details provided after the code).
The code:
!pip install einops 
!pip install torch==1.13.0 torchvision==0.14.0 torchaudio==0.13.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
!pip install packaging
!pip install timm==0.4.12
!pip install pytest chardet yacs termcolor
!pip install submitit tensorboardX
!pip install triton==2.0.0
!pip install causal-conv1d  # causal_conv1d-1.0.0+cu118torch1.13cxx11abiFALSE-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
!pip install mamba-ssm  # mmamba_ssm-1.0.1+cu118torch1.13cxx11abiFALSE-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
!pip install scikit-learn matplotlib thop h5py SimpleITK scikit-image medpy yacs

The issue:
Collecting causal-conv1d
  Downloading causal_conv1d-1.5.0.post8.tar.gz (9.4 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-7lh6rfnr/causal-conv1d_3261fd5c803a42e080e553c8d8af4798/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
          from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CppExtension, CUDAExtension, CUDA_HOME, HIP_HOME
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 25, in <module>
          from pkg_resources import packaging  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
      ImportError: cannot import name 'packaging' from 'pkg_resources' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py)
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
Collecting mamba-ssm
  Downloading mamba_ssm-2.2.4.tar.gz (91 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 91.8/91.8 kB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jb2gu742/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jb2gu742/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jb2gu742/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jb2gu742/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 367, in <module>
          from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
      ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-env-jb2gu742/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/lib/../../nvidia/cusparse/lib/libcusparse.so.12: undefined symbol: __nvJitLinkComplete_12_4, version libnvJitLink.so.12
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I verified that the setuptools, pip, and packaging libraries are up-to-date and properly installed. I didn’t find any issues with them, but I still encounter the problem.
Could someone help me identify the cause of this problem or suggest any fixes?

Is there a dependency or configuration specific to the Mamba transformer that I might be missing?
Are there known compatibility issues when using Mamba for medical image detection tasks?

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
